# python: How to create CPU load that block asyncio event loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

For sake of learning, I want to write a small code snippet to illustrate how to block asyncio event loop with a function that perform CPU load. See below, what I find is, taskA not blocking taskB and vice versa. Instead, taskA and taskB execution is interleaved. This is the point of confusion.
Further I understand create_task will spawn the two tasks on different thread. Thus preemptive multi-tasking was the reason why I see taskA interleaves with taskB execution (And explains why I am not seeing the blocking expected)

```
import asyncio
import threading
from datetime import datetime

def log(msg):
    print(f"{datetime.now()} {msg}")

def blocking_task(task_name):
    num_iter = 100
    log(f"{task_name} started, thread_id: {threading.get_ident()}\n")
    for i in range(num_iter):
        log(f"{i}/{num_iter} executing {task_name} ...")  # This will show taskA and taskB interleave (i.e. not blocking each other)

    log(f"{task_name} finished")

async def taskA(loop):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_task, "Blocking Task A")

async def taskB(loop):
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_task, "Blocking Task B")

async def async_main():
    log(f"async_main thread_id: {threading.get_ident()}")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    
    task_a = asyncio.create_task(taskA(loop))
    task_b = asyncio.create_task(taskB(loop))

    await asyncio.gather(task_a, task_b)
    
    log("Async main finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log(f"Main thread ID: {threading.get_ident()}")
    
    asyncio.run(async_main())
    
    log("Main thread finished")
```

Can someone modify this code so taskA and taskB blocks each other?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you running the work in an executor if you want to block the event loop?

Comment: "Further I understand create_task will spawn the two tasks on different thread" - no it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
def log(msg):
    print(f"{datetime.now()} {msg}")

async def blocking_task(task_name):
    num_iter = 100
    log(f"{task_name} started, thread_id: {threading.get_ident()}\n")
    for i in range(num_iter):
        log(f"{i}/{num_iter} executing {task_name} ...")  # This will show taskA and taskB interleave (i.e. not blocking each other)
        await asyncio.sleep(0) # If you comment this out, taskA and taskB wont be interleaving!!! i.e. block each other
    log(f"{task_name} finished")

async def taskA(loop):
    await blocking_task("Blocking Task A")

async def taskB(loop):
    await blocking_task("Blocking Task B")

async def async_main():
    log(f"async_main thread_id: {threading.get_ident()}")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    '''
    If you do this, tasks will be on separate threads and you wont see blocking happen.
        task_a = asyncio.create_task(taskA(loop))
        task_b = asyncio.create_task(taskB(loop))
        await asyncio.gather(task_a, task_b)
    '''
    await asyncio.gather(taskA(loop), taskB(loop))
    
    log("Async main finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log(f"Main thread ID: {threading.get_ident()}")
    
    asyncio.run(async_main())
    
    log("Main thread finished")
```